# Is CallNamedPipe on windows thread safe

Tags: windows, concurrency, thread-safety, named-pipes

There are several threads calling CallNamedPipe concurrently to send messages to a same named pipe. Is the method CallNamedPipe on windows thread safe, should I use mutex to protect the concurrent access to the same named pipe?

Comment: You have 7 answered questions, but only one answer accepted. Please accept answers that were useful for your case.

Comment: It requires a message-type pipe and writes a single message, specifically to ensure the operation is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is inherently thread safe, because it doesn't use a handle, a buffer, or anything else on the client side that the two (or more) threads might try to access simultaneously.  Each time you call `CallNamedPipe` it opens a new instance of the named pipe, sends the message, and closes the handle.

(The fact that the threads are accessing different instances of the same named pipe simultaneously isn't a problem.  It's no different from multiple processes accessing different instances of the same named pipe simultaneously, and if that weren't permitted named pipes would be much less useful than they are.)